# In Flutter, how can I make a list view which is infinite both to the top and to the bottom?

Tags: listview, scroll, flutter, infinite-scroll

In Flutter, how can I make a list view which is infinite both to the top and to the bottom?

In other words, infinite scroll both to the negative and positive directions.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20608

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

As of December 2018 just use this: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/infinite_listview

**Old answer:**

Use it like this:

```
InfiniteListView.builder(itemBuilder: itemBuilder);
```

Here's the code:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //
    List<double> heights =
        new List<double>.generate(100, (i) => Random().nextInt(90).toDouble() + 45.0);

    var itemBuilder = (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Card(
        child: Container(
          height: heights[index % 100],
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Center(
              child: MaterialButton(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Text('ITEM $index'),
            onPressed: () => print("PRESSED $index"),
          )),
        ),
      );
    };

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Infinite ListView')),
      body: InfiniteListView.builder(itemBuilder: itemBuilder),
    );
  }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class InfiniteListView extends StatefulWidget {
  //
  const InfiniteListView.builder({Key key, this.itemBuilder}) : super(key: key);

  final IndexedWidgetBuilder itemBuilder;

  @override
  _InfinitListViewState createState() => _InfinitListViewState();
}    

class _UnboundedScrollPosition extends ScrollPositionWithSingleContext {
  _UnboundedScrollPosition({
    ScrollPhysics physics,
    ScrollContext context,
    ScrollPosition oldPosition,
    double initialPixels,
  }) : super(
          physics: physics,
          context: context,
          oldPosition: oldPosition,
          initialPixels: initialPixels,
        );

  @override
  double get minScrollExtent => double.negativeInfinity;

  /// There is a feedback-loop between aboveController and belowController. When one of them is
  /// being used, it controlls the other. However if they get out of sync, for timing reasons,
  /// the controlled one with try to controll the other, and the jump will stop the real controller.
  /// For this reason, we can't let one stop the other (idle and ballistics) in this situattion.
  void jumpToWithoutGoingIdleAndKeepingBallistic(double value) {
    if (pixels != value) {
      forcePixels(value);
    }
  }
}

class _UnboundedScrollController extends ScrollController {
  //
  _UnboundedScrollController({
    double initialScrollOffset = 0.0,
    keepScrollOffset = true,
    debugLabel,
  }) : super(
            initialScrollOffset: initialScrollOffset,
            keepScrollOffset: keepScrollOffset,
            debugLabel: debugLabel);

  @override
  _UnboundedScrollPosition createScrollPosition(
    ScrollPhysics physics,
    ScrollContext context,
    ScrollPosition oldPosition,
  ) {
    return _UnboundedScrollPosition(
      physics: physics,
      context: context,
      oldPosition: oldPosition,
      initialPixels: initialScrollOffset,
    );
  }

  void jumpToWithoutGoingIdleAndKeepingBallistic(double value) {
    assert(positions.isNotEmpty, 'ScrollController not attached.');
    for (_UnboundedScrollPosition position in new List<ScrollPosition>.from(positions))
      position.jumpToWithoutGoingIdleAndKeepingBallistic(value);
  }
}

class _InfinitListViewState extends State<InfiniteListView> {
  //
  _UnboundedScrollController _positiveController;
  _UnboundedScrollController _negativeController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Instantiate the negative and positive list positions, relative to one another.
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _negativeController
        .jumpTo(-_negativeController.position.extentInside - _positiveController.position.pixels));

    _positiveController?.dispose();
    _negativeController?.dispose();
    _positiveController = _UnboundedScrollController(keepScrollOffset: false);
    _negativeController = _UnboundedScrollController();

    // ---

    // The POSITIVE list moves the NEGATIVE list, but only if the NEGATIVE list position would change.
    _positiveController.addListener(() {
      var newNegativePosition =
          -_negativeController.position.extentInside - _positiveController.position.pixels;
      var oldNegativePosition = _negativeController.position.pixels;

      if (newNegativePosition != oldNegativePosition) {
        _negativeController.jumpToWithoutGoingIdleAndKeepingBallistic(newNegativePosition);
      }
    });

    // ---

    // The NEGATIVE list moves the POSITIVE list, but only if the POSITIVE list position would change.
    _negativeController.addListener(() {
      var newBelowPosition =
          -_positiveController.position.extentInside - _negativeController.position.pixels;
      var oldBelowPosition = _positiveController.position.pixels;

      if (newBelowPosition != oldBelowPosition) {
        _positiveController.jumpToWithoutGoingIdleAndKeepingBallistic(newBelowPosition);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _positiveController.dispose();
    _negativeController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //
    var sliverList = SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, int index) {
        return widget.itemBuilder(context, -index - 1);
      }),
    );

    var negativeList = CustomScrollView(
      physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      controller: _negativeController,
      reverse: true,
      slivers: [sliverList],
    );

    var positiveList = ListView.builder(
      controller: _positiveController,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return widget.itemBuilder(context, index);
      },
    );

    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        negativeList,
        _ControlledIgnorePointer(
          child: positiveList,
          controller: _positiveController,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _ControlledIgnorePointer extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  //
  final ScrollController controller;

  const _ControlledIgnorePointer({Key key, @required this.controller, Widget child})
      : assert(controller != null),
        super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  _ControlledRenderIgnorePointer createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return new _ControlledRenderIgnorePointer(controller: controller);
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(BuildContext context, _ControlledRenderIgnorePointer renderObject) {
    renderObject..controller = controller;
  }
}

/// Render object that is invisible to hit testing in offsets that depend on the controller.
class _ControlledRenderIgnorePointer extends RenderProxyBox {
  _ControlledRenderIgnorePointer({RenderBox child, ScrollController controller})
      : _controller = controller,
        super(child) {
    assert(_controller != null);
  }

  ScrollController get controller => _controller;
  ScrollController _controller;
  set controller(ScrollController value) {
    assert(value != null);
    if (value == _controller) return;
    _controller = value;
  }

  @override
  bool hitTest(HitTestResult hitTestResult, {Offset position}) {
    bool ignore = -controller.position.pixels > position.dy;
    var boolResult = ignore ? false : super.hitTest(hitTestResult, position: position);
    return boolResult;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think to solve this you can actually use build in features of flutter. Good sample was posted in Flutter feature request issue here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20608

Idea behind this is that instead of using CustomScrollView widget, that actually puts your slivers in viewPort , you can create your own ScrollView, that will define "center" prop (https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Viewport/center.html). In that way Flutter will build SliverList, that has Key same as defined in center, as future list, and SliverList before center - as reverse list. And with SliverBuilder you can make infinite list view in both directions, since it will be called only when ViewPort decides to render next child, to place it in Scollable container (as an example you can read about lazy render here https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SliverList-class.html)